# C# generate TypeScript class with TypeGen and set [immerable] = true

Tags: c#, typescript, immer.js

We are using TypeGen to generate TypeScript classes from our C# classes.

It works like this:

```
[ExportTsClass]
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyField { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Generates:

```
export class MyClass {
    myField: string;
    myProperty: number;
    myProperty2: string;
}
```

https://typegen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatisgenerated.html

This works really well but we have now started using `Immer` with `React Redux`. For classes to work it needs to set `[immerable] = true` like any of the examples below:

```
import {immerable} from "immer"

class Foo {
    [immerable] = true // Option 1

    constructor() {
        this[immerable] = true // Option 2
    }
}

Foo[immerable] = true // Option 3
```

https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/complex-objects

Is this possible to generate via `TypeGen`?

```
import {immerable} from "immer"

export class MyClass {
    [immerable] = true
    myField: string;
    myProperty: number;
    myProperty2: string;
}
```

I have looked at all `TypeGen attributes` but haven't found anything that seems to work. `TsTypeAttribute` could go a long way but no idea how to solve brackets around `immerable`.

https://typegen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/attributes.html#tstypeattribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
import MyClass from "../MyClass";
import { immerable } from "immer";
export class ImmerMyClass extends MyClass {
    [immerable] = true;
}
```